# No carga el framework DataTable en modo sin conexión

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, django, datatables

Estoy trabajando con la web y mientras estoy sin conexión a internet se muestra todo de lo más bien pero al conectar a internet las tablas pierden estilos y se distorsionan algunas cosas.

Estoy trabajando con ***datatable.js***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con *Django 1.11.13*, ya le hice un `collectstatic` y sigue con el mismo problema. Dejo cómo tengo el trabajo en tengo 3 *templates*, uno es donde se encuentran el *template base* que tiene las librerías de *JavaScript* y *CSS*, y en los demás los *templates* de cada proyecto, y un *static* ubicado en `src/static`, que es donde está todo el *JavaScript* y *CSS*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo puesto en **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/src/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'src/static')]
```

Comment: Pero te da un 404 a los archivos js y css?

Comment: esta linea me la pone de color amarillo en la consola "GET /src/static/jquery_3.2.1/css/dataTables.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1730

Comment: Ese es el problema no esta encontrando el css que le da el estilo al dataTable.

Comment: pero cuando esta trabajando sin conexión si lo encuentra y tambien le cambie la dirección que en vez de buscar dataTable local que lo busque en internet entonces si se muestra bien

Comment: Cuando trabajas sin conexión no te da el error 404?

Comment: no, no da el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Haz lo siguiente:**

Si está en **DEBUG**, establezca la variable **STATICFILES_DIRS = ("path/to/static")** en tu **settings.py**. Debería funcionar solo en el modo **DEBUG**.

Si desea que también funcione en modo de despliegue, configure la variable raíz de **STATIC_ROOT = ("path/to/static_root")** en **settings.py**. Luego, ejecuta **python manage.py collectstatic** y también debería funcionar.

Y ahora, para una mejor comprensión de cómo django maneja los archivos estáticos:

- Django tiene algunos lugares predefinidos para buscar archivos
  estáticos y recopilarlos; tu especifica dónde encontrarlos con
  **STATICFILES_FINDERS** en tu **settings.py**. Por defecto, busca la carpeta **static** dentro de sus aplicaciones. Puedes decirle a Django que
  busque archivos estáticos en otras partes configurando la variable
  **STATICFILES_DIRS** (lista o tupla de rutas).
- En el modo **DEBUG**, los archivos estáticos se seleccionan de estas rutas (no de static_root donde se recopilan los archivos).
- Cuando ejecuta **python manage.py collectstatic**, Django recorre todos los directorios donde se encuentran los archivos estáticos y los coloca en tu static root. Cuando se ejecuta en modo de implementación, los archivos estáticos se sirven desde este directorio.

**PD:** Lo que hago normalmente es crear una aplicación llamada common y crear un directorio estático dentro para colocar todos los css, js comunes para mi proyecto (y también para las plantillas). De esta manera, no tengo que especificar la variable **STATICFILES_DIRS**.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24200094/10158153)

Esta es una solución para **static/media/template access** en **django** para **windows**:

**settings.py**

```
import os.path

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
```

Comment: puse STATIC_ROOT = 'static/' y después python manage.py collectstatic me copio todos los archivos estaticos para allí y cambie DEBUG=False y no me reconoce nada de los staticos

Comment: estas usando windows? Acabo de editar mi respuesta, revisala

Comment: estoy utilizando windows 10 en la pc del desarrollo que esta independiente del servidor  sin conexión y linux 16.4 en el servidor que las pc que se conectan al servidor algunas tienen internet y otras no

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, al final esta lo nuevo lo probastes?

Comment: y para linux que es donde voy a desplegar y tampoco tiene internet

Comment: si lo cambie pero cuando cambio el debug a false no encuentra la direccion de static

Comment: Con el DEBUG desactivado, Django ya no se encargará de los archivos estáticos: su servidor web de producción (Apache o algo así) debería ocuparse de eso. Yo coloque una solución cuando estas en modo despliegue no te sirvio tampoco?